# How to add multiple arguments from a file listing those argument?

Tags: shell

I want to submit homework file from a submit list by using shell. But I don't know how to import multiple arguments from the file. Suppose I have five hw to submit, and the file content shows these names.
a
b
c
d
e. Each name is on a new line.

I tried to use `$(<submit-file-list)` to pass those arguments but it turns out. abcde is passed as a whole instead of being passed individually to 5 variables.

The error message says 
a
b
c
d
e: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work.  I suspect you are double quoting the process substitution.  Consider:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

case $# in
1) echo There is $# arg;;
*) echo There are $# args;;
esac
for x; do echo arg: "$x"; done
$ ./a.sh $(< submit-file-list )
There are 5 args
arg: a
arg: b
arg: c
arg: d
arg: e
$ ./a.sh "$(< submit-file-list )"
There is 1 arg
arg: a
b
c
d
e
```